# Which Python framework would you prefer for a WebUI based desktop application?

Tags: web-apps, python, framework, django

I have a software in mind, that I want to develop. The application is already working on a desktop Python tkinter application, but the UI capabilities are too limited, and have to be changed to a Web based solution due to scalability issues.

From the user point of view, I would like to have a web based UI that has the following requirements:

- The application needs to communicate with other computers in the LAN (usually with SSH over Paramiko or TCP) and execute certain shell commands, and upload / download files from/to the user via the web interface.
- The UI needs to be **interactive**, and updateable from server side ( example: backend has a periodic health check for network resources, if some fails it needs to be updated in a web UI with a color change).
- The application needs to be easily portable (and usable under Linux & Windows as well).
- Coding needs to be done in python, as the majority of the backend functionalities are already implemented there. I have little to no knowledge in JavaScript, therefore I would rather have everything done in the python code, and keep the HTML/JavaScript to the bare minimum.

*Sidenote:*
I'm a beginner web developer, and I'm aiming for a scalable but minimum viable product with this project.

**What I have in mind are:**:

- Django
- Flask

> Which one would be more suitable for these requirements, and why?

I can see that Django is a huge (and a bit terrifying) framework the comes with batteries included, but is it configurable enough without raping the framework that such application can be built on top of it?

Is Flask scalable enough in the long run to be sustainable and maintainable?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would go for Flask, its much smaller than Django and less intimidating. 
And much easier to understand, it has a simple structure and very easy to get started with. 
At the same time, it is very capable. I developed a whole web application for an educational institution based on Flask, Python, HTML and CSS alone. (had to input a little bit of javascript but not much)
i'd recommend this tutorial to get started:
https://blog.miguelgrinberg.com/post/the-flask-mega-tutorial-part-i-hello-world

its a very good tutorial to get started with Flask.